# Emoticons Box click adds to input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was hoping for an extra pair of eyes since I'm stuck.
The code is suppose to work so when you click the Emoticon, `:wow:` will show up in the input, but for unknown reasons I simply cannot get it working:

```
//Smiley to Input
$(function () {

    function caretPos() {
        var el = document.getElementById("chatline");
        var pos = 0;
        // IE Support
        if (document.selection) {
            el.focus();
            var Sel = document.selection.createRange();
            var SelLength = document.selection.createRange().text.length;
            Sel.moveStart('character', -el.value.length);
            pos = Sel.text.length - SelLength;
        }
        // Firefox support
        else if (el.selectionStart || el.selectionStart == '0') pos = el.selectionStart;

        return pos;
    }

    $('#emoticons a').click(function () {
        var smiley = $(this).attr('title'),

            caretPos = caretPos(),

            strBegin = $('#chatline').val().substring(0, caretPos),
            strEnd = $('#chatline').val().substring(caretPos);

        $('#chatline').val(strBegin + " " + smiley + " " + strEnd);

    });

    //Hide and Show Smiley Box
    var $container = $('#smiley-container');
    $('#inputsmile').click(function () {
        $container.toggleClass('smileysclosed smileysopen');
    });
    $(document).click(function (event) {
        if ($container.hasClass('smileysopen') && !$(event.target).closest('.smileysopen, #inputsmile').length) {
            $container.toggleClass('smileysclosed smileysopen');
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Here's a Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JVDES/172/

Comment: Should it work like this one? http://jsfiddle.net/pkysylevych/JVDES/173/

Comment: Thats exactly it, thank you so much!